# Crystal Reports BusinesObject Header issue

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, report, business-objects

The company I'm working for has an older version of Crystal Reports before it was part of SAP, it was part of buinessobjects. We have version 11.5 of crystal reports businessobjects.

I am running into a unique issue with one report. When I schedule the report to run on a weekly basis, it adds an attachement Excel document. The issue is that the headers are missing. I have checked off the option to include headers in the attachment, but it is still not showing up.

I'm not sure why this is, because when I run the report directly in Crystal Reports, it shows the headers and I'm able to export it as an excel (data only) from Crystal Reports and the headers come accross.

It is only when I schedule the report to run it does not give the headers. I have tried all the options I can think of and done research, but the version my company is running is so old, that it is hard to find information on how to do things.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting in Excel Data Only ?
When you export to Excel (Data Only), under the Excel Format Options, choose Custom.

Expand the Options.

Ensure to uncheck Simplify page headers

Comment: This was done and still no luck. I also have "Export Headers and Footers" checked.